# Clear all radio buttons in a page

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have lot of dynamically generated radio buttons in my [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) project. They may be checked based on the values in a database. I want to clear all radio buttons in a button click. How can I do that?

Comment: I'm sure there's some efficient way to do this with JQuery. Not an expert though, but a quick google on that could deliver some results I think.

Comment: @Joachim - he is using WinForms.

Comment: Loop through all the controls and check their type.  Then delete if they are radio buttons.

Comment: My bad. Forget I said anything.

Comment: Are you trying to uncheck all the radio buttons, or remove them?

Comment: clear all radio buttons? There should always be one button checked in each group, no?

Comment: "clear all radio buttons?" what exactly are you asking, to remove the controls or set them to unchecked? This is terrible wording.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    var cntls = GetAll(this, typeof(RadioButton));
    foreach (Control cntrl in cntls)
    {
        RadioButton _rb = (RadioButton)cntrl;
        if (_rb.Checked)
        {
            _rb.Checked = false;
        }
    }
}

public IEnumerable<Control> GetAll(Control control, Type type)
{
    var controls = control.Controls.Cast<Control>();
    return controls.SelectMany(ctrls => GetAll(ctrls, type)).Concat(controls).Where(c => c.GetType() == type);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Both will do it below, as long as _radioContainer is a GroupBox.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    // This will remove the radiobuttons completely...
    _radioContainer.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>().ToList().ForEach(p => _radioContainer.Controls.Remove(p));

    // Either of the below will clear the checked state
    _radioContainer.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>().ToList().ForEach(p => p.Checked = false);

    foreach (RadioButton radio in _radioContainer.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>().ToList()) {
        if (radio.Checked == true) {
            radio.Checked = false;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If your radiobuttons span across multiple groupboxes, you can use the "OfType" extension to search for groupboxes first, then, search for the radiobuttons within each groupbox.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered a similar problem, where none of these other answers were useful.

I wanted to initialize a Winform Dialog with 2 Radiobuttons, that should be both unchecked. The user has to make an explicit choice, before something is selected (like in this question: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/76181/radio-buttons-with-none-selected).

Problem was: the first RadioButton (the one with the lower `TabIndex`) was always pre-checked. Manually unchecking one, just checked the other one (no matter if in constructor or at the `Load` Event).

Resolution: set the `TabStop` property to false for both `RadioButtons`. Don't ask me why though.

Comment: Thanks for the solution! If `TabStop` is set to `true`, then one of the RadioButtons (lowest `TabIndex`) is automatically selected, even if you try to uncheck it programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the case, but you may have radio buttons nested inside of other Controls. If that's the case you will need to go through all of the .Controls Collections of all of your controls in order to find them all and switch them off. You can use this helper function to do that:

```
    void ExecuteOnAllChildren<U>(Control c, Action<Control> T) where U : Control
    {
        c.Controls.OfType<U>().ToList().ForEach(a => T(a) );

        foreach(Control childControl in c.Controls)
            ExecuteOnAllChildren<U>(childControl, T);

    }
```

Use it by saying:

```
    ExecuteOnAllChildren<RadioButton>(this, a => { a.Checked = false; });
```

(I assume "this" is your Form. Otherwise replace "this" with the form that you would like to do all of the replaces with.)

Answer (score 0):

```
void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Control ctrl in Controls)
    {
        if (ctrl is Panel)
        {
            foreach (Control rdb in ctrl.Controls)
            {
                if (rdb is RadioButton && ((RadioButton)rdb).Checked == true)
                {
                    ((RadioButton)rdb).Checked = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This clears all the checked radio buttons on a button click.