# How to count the number of radio buttons belonging to same group in VS C# 2010 ?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want a number of radio buttons to be in the same group. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: will you be knowing the groupname or it can be anything?

Comment: Yes I know the groupname.

Answer (score 0):

### Use `asp:RadioButtonList`

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblMyList" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Male" Value="Male"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Female" Value="Female"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Comment: What you have provided is not my answer.I want to use the number of radio buttons of this list in ".cs" file.So please tell me that.

Comment: @user2893698 So, `rblMyList.Items` will return the number items in your list.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for getting Radiobutton with same groupname

C#:

```
 int count = 0;
        foreach (RadioButton rb in divContainer.Controls.OfType<System.Web.UI.WebControls.RadioButton>())
        {
            if(rb.GroupName=="a")
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
```

Note:  asp:RadioButtonList is also a better option

Answer (score 0):

Try this: (based on Renju vinod answer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7025590/clear-all-radio-buttons-in-a-page))

```
    public IEnumerable<Control> GetAll(Control control, Type type)
    {
        var controls = control.Controls.Cast<Control>();
        return controls.SelectMany(ctrls => GetAll(ctrls, type)).Concat(controls).Where(c => c.GetType() == type);
    }
```

Now you can get this like below

```
        string GroupName = "MyGroupName"; // Your known group name
        int numberOfRadioOfThisGroup = 0;
        var cntls = GetAll(this, typeof(RadioButton));
        foreach (Control cntrl in cntls)
        {
            RadioButton rb = (RadioButton)cntrl;
            if (rb.GroupName == GroupName)
            {
                numberOfRadioOfThisGroup++;
            }
        }

        // numberOfRadioOfThisGroup will now have the count of number of radiobuttons belonging to your group
```