# clear the fields on a win form on click event

Tags: c#

[image]

Hi Guys. I am working on a project using visual studio C#, and here is an image of my win form now what i an doing is entering the value in the fields o this form and saving the to my database but after reloading this form all the previous values are there. want i want is that when  i click the SAVE button in this form it must save all the values in my database and then clear all the previous values in the text fields + radio buttons etc.
Please help me what will be the code for this process and where should i write this code?

Comment: I don't know why they are still there since you didn't provide code of your program but take a look at these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811229/how-to-clear-the-text-of-all-textboxes-in-the-form and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7025590/clear-all-radio-buttons-in-a-page

Comment: Resetting control properties should not bog down any programmer.  If you don't want to write the code then just create a new instance of the form class and show it, dispose the old one.

Comment: Hans Passant. Can you please guide me more on the same thing? i am just a beginner

Answer (score 1):

```
private void btnSaveCick(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
  //save your data here



  //after saving your data call the CLearControls() function
  ClearControls(this);
}

void ClearControls(Control control)
{
  foreach (Control c in control.Controls)
  {
    if (c is TextBox)
      ((TextBox)c).Clear();
    else if (c is RadioButton)
      ((RadioButton)c).Checked = false;
    else if (c is ComboBox)
      ((ComboBox)c).SelectedIndex = -1;

    if(c.HasChildren)
      ClearControls(c);
  }
}
```

Comment: I didn't downvote but this will only clear `TextBox` objects, leaving RadioButtons and ComboBox dirty.

Comment: i am just trying to reset all me fields on this form as they are in the above image when i click the save button.

Comment: @Taz: you can create seperate function `ClearControls()` and call this function after saving your form data , check my edited answer .

Comment: For `RadioButton`, I would just set the first item `Checked` property to true. This will set the others to false. This will also work in case your RadioButtons resides in a container (the loop in your code will miss this case).

Comment: @etaiso: added scenario to clear the child elements aswell. i agree with you that setting first radio button makes sense but identifying it among others is bit complex(as we dont know the name of first radio button)